# 特定の単語以外にマッチする正規表現

Tags: c#, 正規表現

C#にて、特定の単語以外にマッチするパターンが書けず困っています。
一文字であれば [^abc] で 'abc' 以外にマッチさせることが出来ますが、単語の場合はどうしたら良いのでしょうか？
否定先読み・否定戻り読みを使う事で一応出来るのですが、これ以外に方法は有りませんか？

Comment: 否定先読み・否定戻り読みを使いたくない理由はなんでしょうか？

Comment: キャプチャが必要になった時に、否定先読み・否定戻り読みとは別にパターンが必要になる為、可読性に欠ける事や、パフォーマンスに差し支えているのではないかといった不安があるので代替パターンを探しています

Comment: 限定的な意味での「正規表現」に限ると、一般的にやるには一旦DFAに展開して受け入れ条件を逆転してから正規表現に直すという方法(かそれと等価な方法)しか知られていません。最悪O(2^(2^n))かかります。http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5125/regular-expressions-finding-negation-of-regular-expression 効率的な手法が(おそらく)存在しない理由は http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337458/is-there-a-way-to-negate-a-regular-expression 但し、backreferenceや先読み戻り読みがある拡張正規表現はこの議論には縛られません。

Comment: 正規表現の外側で問題を解決することが許されるなら、その単語にマッチした場合を失敗として扱いマッチしなかった場合を成功として扱うのが一番簡単でしょう。

Comment: 正規表現外で確認ということですか。無理に一つのパターンで全てを解決させようとしたのが間違いだったというわけですね。参考になりました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ある文字列を含まないものにマッチする正規表現](http://www.din.or.jp/~ohzaki/regex.htm#Without)のようになり可読性も低下しバックトラックも頻発しパフォーマンスも悪いです。否定先読みを使用した方が可読性も高くパフォーマンスもいいため、正規表現エンジンがサポートしているのであれば使用すべきです。